# Looking for a word similar to “optimize”, but for describing articles

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose I wrote an article, and I want other gurus to make it better, first thought was *optimize my article*, but after looking up that word, it means *do something most efficiently*, so it’s far from my meaning.

What word should I use in replace of *optimize*?

> “***_*__** my article”

Comment: You could use 'polish', assuming no major errors needed fixing.

Comment: General Reference. -1 Research not shown. Please see the [faq].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What other gurus would be doing to your article would be *revise* or *review* it. In the Acknowledgements section, you'd then typically say, "Many thanks to Guru Jack and Guru Jane for reviewing early versions of the draft" or something to that extent.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the verb *improve*.

Comment: Or *polish up* for something a bit more casual, and *refine* for something a bit more formal.

Comment: Yes, *refine* is what immediately came to my mind.

Answer (score 4):

I would say 'copy-edit' — as in, when you say guru, if you mean someone who knows the subject matter that you want to make sure what you've written makes sense, is accurate, and isn't being overly wordy or assuming the reader knows something that may need clarification.

So may be suitable if you wanted someone to review what you've written for problems, but not making their own changes in the tone or content of the piece above and beyond this.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_editing):

> The "five Cs" summarize the copy editor's job: Make the copy clear,
>   correct, concise, complete, and consistent. Copy editors should *make
>   it say what it means, and mean what it says*.
>
> Typically, copy editing involves correcting spelling, punctuation,
>   grammar, terminology, jargon, and semantics, and ensuring that the
>   text adheres to the publisher's style or an external style guide.
>
> …
>
> Copy editors are expected to ensure that the text flows, that it is
>   sensible, fair, and accurate, and that any legal problems have been
>   addressed. If a passage is unclear or an assertion seems questionable,
>   the copy editor may ask the writer to clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

How about asking them to ***amend*** your work?

v. to change for the better

Comment: When providing a definition, please also provide a link to the source.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we need a neologistic verb: Wiki me!

Answer (score 0):

Optimize indicates an improvement of some kind. So with an audience in mind you could either

- simplify for a less knowledgable audience
  or
- embelish for a more knowledgable audience

Comment: This really doesn't quite answer the question.  Suppose the OP has written to exactly the right audience but wants his article to be better than it is.  Something along the lines of *polish* is required.